# Want to reverse my String location and special character should be there as it is

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I've a String as Input like

```
input = 'apple&&bat&&&cat&&dog&elephant'
```

and i want to reverse the words and special character should be remains same in their place.

```
Output - 'elephant&&dog&&&cat&&bat&apple'
```

Exactly, i don't know in which approach i have to solve this problem.
But, yes i've tried this

with this i got the reverse word but how to place the '&' in their respective position i don't know.

```
input = 'apple&&bat&&&cat&&dog&elephant'

ab = input.split('&')[::-1]

print ab
```

output

```
['elephant', 'dog', '', 'cat', '', '', 'bat', '', 'apple']
```

But my output should be

```
'elephant&&dog&&&cat&&bat&apple'
```

Comment: Step one, split it up into its constituent parts. Step two, identify the words you want to rearrange (identify them in-place). Step 3, replace each word with its counterpart. Step 4, reassemble into one string.

Comment: how to place the special character('&') as it is.. that im not getting..

Comment: If you split the string so that you have one array containing words and non-words as separate elements, all you have to do afterwards is to replace the elements with the words and leave the non-words in the original position.

Comment: By "split the string", I would not use `.split(..)` as this will remove the split characters. Instead I would loop through the string categorizing part by part.

Comment: could you please give me a sample code for this.. how to loop through the string.. bcoz if here you will apply loop on this string the it will separate one one letter..

Answer (score 0):

First get separate lists of the words and special marks using `re` module:

```
In [2]: import re

In [4]: words = re.findall(r'\w+', input)

In [6]: words
Out[6]: ['apple', 'bat', 'cat', 'dog', 'elephant']

In [7]: special = re.findall(r'\W+', input)

In [8]: special
Out[8]: ['&&', '&&&', '&&', '&']
```

Then reverse the words list:

```
In [11]: rwords = words[::-1]

In [12]: rwords
Out[12]: ['elephant', 'dog', 'cat', 'bat', 'apple']
```

Finally, combine each word with the corresponding mark. Please note that I expand the `special` list by one empty string to make the lists the same length. The final operation is one line of code:

```
In [15]: ''.join(w + s for w, s in zip(rwords, special + ['']))
Out[15]: 'elephant&&dog&&&cat&&bat&apple'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution to the problem that uses only the basic concepts. It navigates the split list from both the left and the right and swaps each pair of encountered words.

```
s = 'apple&&bat&&&cat&&dog&elephant'
words = s.split('&')
idx_left = 0
idx_right = len(words) - 1
while idx_left < idx_right:
   while not words[idx_left]:
       idx_left += 1
   while not words[idx_right]:
       idx_right -= 1
   words[idx_left], words[idx_right] = words[idx_right], words[idx_left] # Swap words
   idx_left += 1
   idx_right -= 1

output = '&'.join(words)
```

The result is

```
'elephant&&dog&&&cat&&bat&apple'
```

Another more advanced approach is to use `groupby` and list slicing:

```
from itertools import groupby

# Split the input string into the list
# ['apple', '&&', 'bat', '&&&', 'cat', '&&', 'dog', '&', 'elephant']
words = [''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(s, lambda c: c == '&')]
n = len(words)
words[::2] = words[n-n%2::-2]  # Swapping (assume the input string does not start with a separator string)
output = ''.join(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another regex solution:

```
>>> import re
>>> # Extract the "words" from the string.
>>> words = re.findall(r'\w+', s)
>>> words
['apple', 'bat', 'cat', 'dog', 'elephant']
>>> # Replace the words with formatting placeholders ( {} )
>>> # then format the resulting string with the words in 
>>> # reverse order
>>> re.sub(r'\w+', '{}', s).format(*reversed(words))
'elephant&&dog&&&cat&&bat&apple'
```