# Reverse string without non letters symbol

Tags: python, string, reverse

I need to reverse only letters in each word. The order of the words and non-letter symbols must remain in their positions. I have a function, but it changes the position of the word.

```
def reverse_string(st):
    stack = []
    for el in st:
        if el.isalpha():
            stack.append(el)
    result = ''
    for el in st:
        if el.isalpha():
            result += stack.pop()
        else:
            result += el
    return result
```

Input string:

```
b3ghcd hg#tyj%h
```

Expected output string:

```
d3chgb hj#ytg%h
```

Comment: Similar [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57522564/want-to-reverse-my-string-location-and-special-character-should-be-there-as-it-i/57535217#57535217](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57522564/want-to-reverse-my-string-location-and-special-character-should-be-there-as-it-i/57535217#57535217)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were really close! Your code is not working because you are applying the reversion to the whole string instead of doing it one word at a time. But just adding an extra step that splits the input string at white spaces (I assume white spaces is what defines words in your input) you'll get your desired result:

```py
def reverse_string(st):
    return ' '.join(reverse_word(word) for word in st.split())

def reverse_word(st):
    stack = []
    for el in st:
        if el.isalpha():
            stack.append(el)
    result = ''
    for el in st:
        if el.isalpha():
            result += stack.pop()
        else:
            result += el
    return result

instr = 'b3ghcd hg#tyj%h'

print(reverse_string(instr)) # prints 'd3chgb hj#ytg%h'
```

---

NOTE:
You can pythonify your code a bit using some built in functions of list comprehension. In this case you'd replace the building of your `stack`.

```py
stack = []
    for el in st:
        if el.isalpha():
            stack.append(el)
```

for one of the following:

`stack = [el for el in st if el.isalpha()]`
or
`stack = list(filter(str.isalpha, st))`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could try the following, which creates a reversed list of the alpha characters only, then inserts the non-alpha characters into their respective positions, and returns the sequence as a string.

```
def rev_str(s):
    x = list(filter(str.isalpha, s[::-1]))
    for i,s_ in enumerate(s):
        if not s_.isalpha():
            x.insert(i, s_)
    return ''.join(x)

instr = 'b3ghcd hg#tyj%h'
outstr = ' '.join(rev_str(s) for s in instr.split())

print(outstr)
d3chgb hj#ytg%h
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the function you provided, one way of doing it is:

```py
import re

def reverse_word(st):
    stack = []
    for el in st:
        if el.isalpha():
            stack.append(el)
    result = ''
    for el in st:
        if el.isalpha():
            result += stack.pop()
        else:
            result += el
    return result

def reverse_string(st):
    return re.sub(r'\S+', lambda match: reverse_word(match.group()), st)

print(reverse_string("b3ghcd hg#tyj%h"))
# "d3chgb hj#ytg%h"
```

Not thoroughly tested, and you might want to use for example `[^\s,.?!;]` or similar instead of `\S`, depending on what kind of 'sentences' you are dealing with.